# DLL load failed while importing tflite_registrar: The specified procedure could not be found

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I'm importing `tensorflow_text` but whenever I run my code I get this error:

This is my `pip freeze`:

```
tensorboard==2.10.1
tensorboard-data-server==0.6.1
tensorboard-plugin-wit==1.8.1
tensorflow==2.10.1
tensorflow-addons==0.19.0
tensorflow-datasets==4.8.1
tensorflow-estimator==2.10.0
tensorflow-hub==0.12.0
tensorflow-intel==2.11.0
tensorflow-io==0.30.0
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem==0.31.0
tensorflow-metadata==1.12.0
tensorflow-model-optimization==0.7.3
tensorflow-probability==0.19.0
text-unidecode==1.3
tf-models-official==2.10.1
tf-slim==1.1.0
tfds-nightly==4.8.1.dev202301120044
...
```

My code:

```
import tensorflow as tf 
import tensorflow_text
```

It stops at line 2, with the rest of my code not executing.

My error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\***\main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import tensorflow_text
  File "C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_text\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from tensorflow_text.core.pybinds import tflite_registrar
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing tflite_registrar: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

I tried installing `tflite_registrar` but it isn't a module.

I found the `init.py` file for `tensorflow_text` and got a screenshot, if it helps at all:

[image]

My site packages:

[image]